# How can you test that a python typing Protocol is a subclass of another Protocol?

Tags: python, inheritance, protocols, typing

The obvious solution to the problem is to use `issubclass`, but this raises `TypeError` (using Python 3.6.7), e.g.

```py
>>> from typing_extensions import Protocol
>>> class ProtoSubclass(Protocol):
...     pass
... 
>>> issubclass(ProtoSubclass, Protocol)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/opt/conda/envs/airflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/typing_extensions.py", line 1265, in __subclasscheck__
    raise TypeError("Instance and class checks can only be used with"
TypeError: Instance and class checks can only be used with @runtime protocols
>>> from typing_extensions import runtime
>>> @runtime
... class ProtoSubclass(Protocol):
...     pass
... 
>>> issubclass(ProtoSubclass, Protocol)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/opt/conda/envs/airflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/typing_extensions.py", line 1265, in __subclasscheck__
    raise TypeError("Instance and class checks can only be used with"
TypeError: Instance and class checks can only be used with @runtime protocols
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For more on the topic of python `Protocols`, see

- https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/protocols.html#using-isinstance-with-protocols

In Python 3.6.7, one way to solve this is to use the `@runtime_checkable` decorator:

```py
>>> from typing_extensions import Protocol
>>> from typing_extensions import runtime_checkable

>>> @runtime_checkable
... class CustomProtocol(Protocol):
...     def custom(self):
...         ...
... 

>>> @runtime_checkable
... class ExtendedCustomProtocol(CustomProtocol, Protocol):
...     def extended(self):
...         ...
... 

>>> issubclass(ExtendedCustomProtocol, CustomProtocol)
True
```

Answer (score 13):

The selected answer, although not wrong, doesn't reflect the actual use of `Protocol`, which is providing structural subtyping. Nominal subtyping was always available to Python 3.

```py
from typing import Protocol, runtime_checkable

@runtime_checkable
class Closable(Protocol):
    def close(self):
        ...

class AnyClass:
    def close(self):
        ...

issubclass(AnyClass, Closable)
#> True
```

Also, `runtime_checkable` is only needed in the base class, even if the class being checked is a `Protocol` subclass.

```py
class ExtendedProtocol(Closable, Protocol):
    ...

class AnotherProtocol(Protocol):
    def close(self):
        ...

class NotAProtocol(Closable):
    # just inherits the protocol's default implementation
    ...

issubclass(ExtendedProtocol, Closable)
#> True
issubclass(AnotherProtocol, Closable)
#> True
issubclass(NotAProtocol, Closable)
#> True
```